# SQL Update Multiple Fields FROM via a SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

This works, but i would like to remove the redundancy.
Is there a way to merge the update with a single select statement so i don't have to use vars?

```
    DECLARE
        @OrgAddress1 varchar,
        @OrgAddress2 varchar,
        @OrgCity varchar,
        @OrgState varchar,
        @OrgZip varchar,
        @DestAddress1 varchar,
        @DestAddress2 varchar,
        @DestCity varchar,
        @DestState varchar,
        @DestZip varchar

    SELECT 
        @OrgAddress1    =   OrgAddress,
        @OrgAddress2    =   OrgAddress2,
        @OrgCity        =   OrgCity,
        @OrgState       =   OrgState,
        @OrgZip         =   OrgZip,
        @DestAddress1   =   DestAddress,
        @DestAddress2   =   DestAddress2,
        @DestCity       =   DestCity,
        @DestState      =   DestState,
        @DestZip        =   DestZip
    FROM 
        ProfilerTest.dbo.BookingDetails 
    WHERE 
        MyID=@MyID

    UPDATE SHIPMENT
    SET
        OrgAddress1     =   @OrgAddress1,
        OrgAddress2     =   @OrgAddress2,
        OrgCity         =   @OrgCity,
        OrgState        =   @OrgState,
        OrgZip          =   @OrgZip,
        DestAddress1    =   @DestAddress1,
        DestAddress2    =   @DestAddress2,
        DestCity        =   @DestCity,
        DestState       =   @DestState,
        DestZip         =   @DestZip
    WHERE 
        MyID2=@ MyID2
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Something like this should work (can't test it right now - from memory):

```
UPDATE SHIPMENT
SET
  OrgAddress1     = BD.OrgAddress1,
  OrgAddress2     = BD.OrgAddress2,
  OrgCity         = BD.OrgCity,
  OrgState        = BD.OrgState,
  OrgZip          = BD.OrgZip,
  DestAddress1    = BD.DestAddress1,
  DestAddress2    = BD.DestAddress2,
  DestCity        = BD.DestCity,
  DestState       = BD.DestState,
  DestZip         = BD.DestZip
FROM
   BookingDetails BD
WHERE 
   SHIPMENT.MyID2 = @MyID2
   AND
   BD.MyID = @MyID
```

Does that help?

Comment: works like a charm, i knew there had to be a way to do an update based a select statement but how was escaping me.

Comment: FYI - this doesn't work in oracle.  Instead, you can use 
<code>
 update  ( select table1.field1 as a1 , table2.field2 as b1
   from table1, table2 where field1 = field2)
 set a1 = b1
note: I think the aliases are necessary if your fields have the same name for some reason.

Comment: @Jody: the question was about SQL Server - not Oracle - so I gave a solution that works in SQL Server.

Comment: @marc_s BUT IT IS GOOD FROM JODY THAT HE INFORM OTHERS ABOUT ORACLE.

Comment: @IbrahimOudah The answer told me what to do and Jody's comment why I hadn't seen this syntax before

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

```
UPDATE s SET
  s.Field1 = q.Field1,
  s.Field2 = q.Field2,
  (list of fields...)
FROM (
  SELECT Field1, Field2, (list of fields...)
  FROM ProfilerTest.dbo.BookingDetails 
  WHERE MyID=@MyID
) q
WHERE s.MyID2=@ MyID2
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do something along the lines of the following

```
UPDATE s
SET
    OrgAddress1 = bd.OrgAddress1,
    OrgAddress2 = bd.OrgAddress2,
    ...
    DestZip = bd.DestZip
FROM
    Shipment s, ProfilerTest.dbo.BookingDetails bd
WHERE
    bd.MyID = @MyId AND s.MyID2 = @MyID2
```

FROM statement can be made more optimial (using more specific joins), but the above should do the trick. Also, a nice side benefit to writing it this way, to see a preview of the UPDATE change `UPDATE s SET` to read `SELECT`! You will then see that data as it would appear if the update had taken place.

Comment: Same difference. It's cleaner to me. I'm not double selecting. I'm getting only the results from s as the come from the FROM clause.

Comment: Well there was a question about why is specify Shipment in the FROM clause instead of near after update. marc_s answer above and this actually have the exact same execution plan in MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

you can use update from...

something like:

update shipment set....
from
shipment
inner join ProfilerTest.dbo.BookingDetails on ...

Answer (score 0):

I would write it this way

```
UPDATE s
SET    OrgAddress1 = bd.OrgAddress1,    OrgAddress2 = bd.OrgAddress2,    
     ...    DestZip = bd.DestZip
--select s.OrgAddress1, bd.OrgAddress1, s.OrgAddress2, bd.OrgAddress2, etc 
FROM    Shipment s
JOIN ProfilerTest.dbo.BookingDetails bd on  bd.MyID =s.MyID2
WHERE    bd.MyID = @MyId
```

This way the join is explicit as implicit joins are a bad thing IMHO. You can run the commented out select (usually I specify the fields I'm updating old and new values next to each other) to make sure that what I am going to update is exactly what I meant to update.

Comment: I'm not sure given the original example there is a one to one (or many) relationship between BookingDetails and Shipment for bd.MyID to s.MyID2. Example given has (admittingly I'm assuming) two different paramters for ids, so I'm assuming the potential for them to be differnet. I agree though that if an eplicit join exists it should be used!

Comment: Didn't even notice that, so perhaps the cross join is the better solution. Only the OP knows for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to solve a similar problem where I added a Sequence number (so that items as grouped by a parent ID, have a Sequence that I can order by (and presumably the user can change the sequence number to change the ordering).

In my case, it's insurance for a Patient, and the user gets to set the order they are assigned, so just going by the primary key isn't useful for long-term, but is useful for setting a default.

The problem with all the other solutions is that certain aggregate functions aren't allowed outside of a SELECT

This SELECT gets you the new Sequence number:

```
select PatientID,
       PatientInsuranceID, 
       Sequence, 
       Row_Number() over(partition by PatientID order by PatientInsuranceID) as RowNum
from PatientInsurance
order by PatientID, PatientInsuranceID
```

This update command, would be simple, but isn't allowed:

```
update PatientInsurance
set Sequence = Row_Number() over(partition by PatientID order by PatientInsuranceID)
```

The solution that worked (I just did it), and is similar to eKek0's solution:

```
UPDATE PatientInsurance
SET  PatientInsurance.Sequence = q.RowNum
FROM (select PatientInsuranceID, 
             Row_Number() over(partition by PatientID order by PatientInsuranceID) as RowNum
      from PatientInsurance
     ) as q 
WHERE PatientInsurance.PatientInsuranceID=q.PatientInsuranceID
```

this lets me select the ID I need to match things up to, and the value I need to set for that ID.  Other solutions would have been fine IF I wasn't using Row_Number() which won't work outside of a SELECT.

Given that this is a 1 time operation, it's coding is still simple, and run-speed is fast enough for 4000+ rows