# Updating Records in Table A based on Records in Table B

Tags: sql, sql-update, projection

I have to write a statement which fills a table (`customers`) with synthetically generated values. There is an addtional constraint that I should only fill those attributes (columns) with a special property (i.e. formally do a projection on them and then operate on them exclusively). These properties are stored in a second table, `attributes`.

My first draft consists of the following two statements:

```
-- Get the attributes (columns) we are interested in only
SELECT attributeID from attributes
WHERE tableID = 'customers'

-- Iterate over each row of customers, filling only those attributes (columns)
-- obtained by the above SELECT statement
UPDATE customers
   SET (use the records from above select statement...)
```

Now my problem is how to put them together. I know there is the possibility of appending a WHERE clause to the `SET` clause, but that would select rows, not columns, as I need. I also read about `PIVOT`, but so far only inside one single table, not two, as is the case here. I would be very thankful for any hint, since I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

is not it you're looking for?
[SQL Update Multiple Fields FROM via a SELECT Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267993/sql-update-multiple-fields-from-via-a-select-statement)

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    Table.col1 = other_table.col1,
    Table.col2 = other_table.col2
FROM
    Table
INNER JOIN
    other_table
ON
    Table.id = other_table.id
```

Comment: This is not Standard SQL so can you state which dialect of SQL (SQL Server?) you have in mind please.

Comment: No, it's standard ANSI-sql. I tested it at least in T-SQL

Comment: At first, thank you for your answer and sorry for my late reply.
The problem is, that the number of columns to update is not known in advance since this is a result of the SELECT on the attributes table. In the meantime we solved the problem by not trying to do it in pure SQL but using Python to generate the SET statement instead.
For more detailed info on this please see my second comment to onedaywhen's post.

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL-92 requires a scalar subquery:

```
UPDATE customers
   SET attributeID = (
                      SELECT A1.attributeID 
                        FROM attributes AS A1
                       WHERE A1.tableID = 'customers'
                     );
```

However, `UPDATE customers...WHERE A1.tableID = 'customers'` "smells" like you may be mixing data with metadata.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @onedaywhen, and please excuse my late one. I think your answer comes very close to what I needed. In the meantime, however, we solved this problem by giving up doing it in pure SQL but using Python for generating the UPDATE statements. The main difficulty when trying to do this in SQL was that the number of columns we get from the attributes table is not known in advance. So it might have been possible to generate a statement similar to that one you proposed, see next comment.

Comment: SET 
    ( SELECT attributeID 
      FROM attributes
      WHERE.tableID = 'customers'
    ) = 
    ('AAAA', 'AA', ...); --number of values must equal number of attributes on left side

Comment: While the „left“ side in the parentheses for defining which columns to update might be possible, we at the latest struggled how to generate the second part on the right side (the 'AAA's) with SQL statements only.
So we decided to do this in Python where we get the list of attributes to be updated from the attributes table first. Since we get these as a Python list it is straightforward to get the number of elements it has and generate both sides of the above SQL SET statement.
So, many thanks again for your help and hopefully this could help you, too.

Comment: ...and you are completely right about that we mix data with metadata. This is a legacy relict and we try to get rid of it step by step.